# How to downgrade Ubuntu 16.04 to 15.10?

Tags: downgrade

I am using an HP pavilion G6 notebook and it has AMD graphic which is not supported by Ubuntu 16.04. I want to downgrade my PC, unless there is any other solution to fix this graphic problem.

Comment: It should be supported by default by Ubuntu. What chipset do you have, that it is not supported?

Comment: Never did it myself - but i can offer some informations regarding downgrade - https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DowngradeHowto

Answer (score 0):

> AMD graphic which is not supported by ubuntu 16.04.

I think you're talking about [fglrx being deprecated in 16.04](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Ubuntu-16.04-Dropping-fglrx). Fglrx is a very old AMD driver, notable for bad performance, and being pretty buggy. It is deprecated on both sides: [it won't work with newer xserver version](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=x.org-server-1.18-video-abi) because of ABI change, and AMD themselves considering the driver legacy.

> if there is any other solution to fix this graphic problem. please give the solution.

Yes, just use the default open source driver. For now this driver being actively developed by AMD, so you may count this as an official driver by AMD. AFAIK for newer cards there's also new AMDGPU driver, which is open-sourced too. If you're into experimentation, you could try adding a PPA with development versions of drivers — but it is, of course, unstable.

You may read the [discussion about the deprecation here](https://www.phoronix.com/forums/forum/phoronix/general-discussion/857070-ubuntu-is-deprecating-fglrx-catalyst-in-16-04-lts).